# Uso de trim en php

Tags: php, lua

Tengo un archivo llamado instrucciones.txt que se llena con la información que el usuario escriba en un textfield, al dar click en el boton guardar.
al crear una nueva linea cada vez que doy click mediante la linea de codigo fwrite ($file, $contenido.PHP_EOL); al final de cada linea se crea un espacio en blanco.
Me han recomendado usar trim pero al hacer esto se unen las lineas que guardo quedando asi: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo puedo guardar linea por linea sin que se cree un espacio en blanco al final?**

Comment: $contenido tiene una sola línea o puede tener varias? Es decir, escribes el fichero con un solo fwrite, o con varios en un bucle?

Comment: Cada vez que doy click en el botón  se debe guardar la linea una debajo de otra, uso un solo fwrite. pero puede tener varias lineas segun las veces que escriba en el textfield y de click en guadar.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con:

```
$lineas = explode("\n", $contenido);
$cad = implode("\n", array_map(trim, $lineas));
fwrite($file, $cad);
```

O si quieres todo en una línea

```
fwrite($file, implode("\n", array_map(trim, explode("\n",$contenido)));
```

Desde hace tiempo todas las funciones de escritura de ficheros tienen en cuenta el sistema operativo y cambian el \n por el correspondiente \r\n en Windows o el simple \n en *nix.